# How to send a variable from Extjs to HTML

Tags: javascript, extjs

Path: app/controller/config/admin.js

In my admin.js controller I set a function which is firing after clicking a button. What that function does is to open a new window where I set an iframe to load a html file.

```
new Ext.Window({
   title : "iframe",
   width : '80%',
   height: '80%',
   layout : 'fit',                        
   items : [{
      xtype : "component",
      width: '100%',
      height: '100%',                
      autoEl : {
         tag : "iframe",
         src : "login.php"                    
      }
   }],
});
```

That code is working pretty much fine, a new window is created with the content in my html file but what I need is to send a variable to my html file when creating the window because I have some logic in my html file.

is there any way to send a variable to my html file which I can get in a script tag ?

the html file is outside the app folder

```
folder  --  app
file    --  login.html
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass variables to HTML, as HTML is barely markup, which does not support any variables. And also, opening new browser-tabs in SPA is by itself questionable, unless this may be some plain print-preview or alike; just show a modal-dialog `Window` instead... with an ExtJS login form, in order not having to pass variables around.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure what you are trying to do but I think you should be able to send whatever params in your src URL as src: `login.php?var=xxxx`.